# git - use an existing branch, but copy latest from current branch to it

Tags: git, git-branch

We have a feature branch (`feature`) that was used a while ago. The changes from `feature` were integrated back to the development branch (`development`). But since then, `development` has been revised, and `feature` hasn't, *i.e.* it has old code. We are revisiting the same feature and would like to reuse this branch. How do we make sure `feature` = `development`?

I'm guessing there is probably a duplicate question out there, but I'm just missing the correct terminology.

Comment: `git checkout -b newfeature development`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to discard the old `feature` branch:

```
git checkout master              # Make sure we are there
git branch -d feature            # Kill old branch dead
git checkout -b feature          # New feature branch, starting at current master
```

But in that case, I'd just leave it lying around (or perhaps rename it to `historic/feature` or such) and just create a new branch for the spanking new feature.

Other options are to rebase `feature` on top of `master` (basically, grafting it on there; changes already applied should just take over).

```
git tag feature save-this-just-in-case   # History rewriting might lose it...
git checkout feature
git rebase master
```

Be careful, branches off `feature` won't follow it around!

Or even just merge the changes in `master` into `feature`:

```
git checkout feature
git merge master
```

**PS:** Before blindly following advise from somebody at the other end of the world posting (semi)anonymously on some random site, *read the manuals* and do some experiments with a scratch (copy of the) repository.

Comment: It's saying that my local feature branch is not the same as the remote, and wants me to pull, but won't that just restore the old feature branch from the remote repository?

Comment: Agreed on rebase, I tend to use merge to keep tracks of multiple versions at once.

Comment: How do I make a scratch copy of the repository?

Comment: @YiminRong, `mkdir scratch; git clone YourFunkyRepo scratch` should do. Under Unix/Linux, if possible this will even hardlink the objects (the real data store), so this won't take much space.

Answer (score 5):

You should merge the branches with `git merge development` from the feature branch.
If you did not change feature it will simply fast-forward to development. Otherwise, simply solve the merging conflicts.

Comment: After this is done, how can I confirm that `feature` = `development`?

Comment: @YiminRong You can use gitk, which is a graphic tool to see git trees

Comment: It shows the remote pointers as they were the last time you pulled or fetched from the remote.

Comment: Sorry, I can't make heads or tails as to what gitk is telling me. I can't see how feature = development using gitk, but apparently there is a .. notation to compare local repositories. These check out, how now my local feature is very different from the remote feature. It won't let me push, saying I need to pull first, but that will overwrite the changes. I'm not sure what to do now. I want remote feature to be the same as my local feature.

Comment: You have to be more advanced than the remote repository to push. It means that if someone else has modified it after your last push, you have to pull and merge before pushing. You should check [there](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches)

Comment: No one has modified the feature branch. Please don't be offended, but I don't understand the content from the git-scm links, it very quickly goes over my head. Like the diagram with the hexadecimal sequences on it, I don't know what those rectangles mean.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49499/discussion-between-math-and-yimin-rong)